# 'Canonically' solving linear ODE system with arbitrary nonhomogeneity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say you have an ODE system of the form

$$u_x=A_\alpha u+f_\alpha,$$

with $A_\alpha$ and $f_\alpha$ varying smoothly with the parameter $\alpha$ (and $f_\alpha$ not necessarily having any particular form in terms of e.g. elementary functions). For any fixed $\alpha$, and particular solution $u_{p,\alpha}$ the solution set to this system is of course

$$u_{p,\alpha}+\mathcal N(\partial_x-A_\alpha).$$

I'd like to smoothly track $u_{p,\alpha}$ as $\alpha$ varies; but since particular solutions are defined up to the nullspace, I need a canonical way of defining $u_{p,\alpha}$.